# Как найти периоды и посчитать отношение их суммы к количеству?

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, list, числовые-последовательности

```
a = [1100111000,1110101110,1101110000,1111000100,1110011011,1110001000,1110001011,1110001000,1101101010,1100111010,1100011010,1111000011,1001111110,1100010011,1100000010,1111010010,1101000111,1001001011,1111000110,1000010001,1000110111,1111000001,1100100011,1011000110,1010011011,1101010010,1110011100,1001101000]

list_1 = []
list_0 = []
c = 0
list_1b = 0
list_0b = 0
counter = 0
list_for_0 = []
list_for_1 = []
answer = []

for r in a:
    for x in str(r):
        if x == '1':
            list_1.append(c)
        else:
            list_0.append(c)
        c += 1
    c = 0
    list_1b = list_1[0]
    list_0b = list_0[0]
    list_0 = []
    list_1 = []
    for x in list_1:
        if list_1b == x:
            list_1b += 1
            counter += 1
        else:
            list_for_1.append(counter)
            counter = 1
            list_1b = x + 1
    list_for_1.append(counter)
    counter = 0
    for x in list_0:
        if list_0b == x:
            list_0b += 1
            counter += 1
        else:
            list_for_0.append(counter)
            counter = 1
            list_0b = x + 1
    list_for_0.append(counter)
    counter = 0
    print(list_for_0)
    print(list_for_1)
    list_for_0 = sum(list_for_0) / len(list_for_0)
    list_for_1 = sum(list_for_1) / len(list_for_1)
    answer.append(list_for_0)
    answer.append(list_for_1)
    list_for_0 = []
    list_for_1 = []
```

Например есть 1110010111,1110001100 надо что бы выдало [1.5,2.33,2.5,2.5]

Надо чтобы считало по сколько периоды с 1 или 0 длятся. Если представить что 1 - дождь ,а 0 - ясно. То можно 1100111000 представить как, 2 дня дождь, 2 дня ясно ,3 дня дождь, 3 дня ясно .То в среднем дождь идет 2.5 дня также как и 'ясно'

Я решил используя списки и переменные:

```
a = 1110001100111
count0 = 0
count1 = 0
count00 = []
count11 = []
for i in str(a):
    if i == '0':
        if count1 != 0:
            count11.append(count1)
            count1 = 0
        count0 += 1
    else:
        if count0 != 0:
            count00.append(count0)
            count0 = 0
        count1 += 1
if count0 == 0: count11.append(count1)
else: count00.append(count0)
print((sum(count11) / len(count11)) / (sum(count00) / len(count00)))
```

Comment: А как вы среднее считаете? И что подразумеваете под _среднее значение 0 и 1 из числа, _? Покажите на конкретном примере почему 1110010111 = 1.5 и 2.33

Comment: Сначала берем группы с 0 :  00 и 0 = 2 и 1, потом находим среднее (2+1) / 2 =1.5

Comment: тоже самое для 1: 111 и 1 и 111 = 3 и 1 и 3 ,среднее (3+1+3) / 3= 2.33

Comment: Школу прогуливали? Или я что-то не так понимаю... Среднее считается делением суммы всех эл-тов на кол-во.. Сумма меняется, а с чего меняться кол-ву? В последовательности как было 10 эл-тов, так и остаётся

Comment: само число 1110010111 - всего лишь порядок

Comment: Выражаться конкретней надо, с примером.. Вы не считаете среднее для чисел

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`itertools.groupby` соберет одинаковые цифры в группы. Результаты будем накапливать в словаре формата `<цифра>: [<количество групп>, <суммарная длина групп>]`. Последний пример показывает проблему с одними нулями. Но это уже другая история.

```
import itertools

array = [
    1100111000, 1110101110, 1101110000, 1111000100, 1110011011,
    1110001000, 1110001011, 1110001000, 1101101010, 1100111010,
    1100011010, 1111000011, 1001111110, 1100010011, 1100000010,
    1111010010, 1101000111, 1001001011, 1111000110, 1000010001,
    1000110111, 1111000001, 1100100011, 1011000110, 1010011011,
    1101010010, 1110011100, 1001101000, 1111111111, 0000000000
]

for a in array:
    d = {}
    for k, g in itertools.groupby(str(a)):
        p = d.setdefault(k, [0, 0])
        p[0] += 1
        p[1] += sum(1 for _ in g)
    print(a, *(f'{k}:{s / n:.2f}' for k, (n, s) in sorted(d.items())))
```

> ```
> $ python average_bit_length.py 
> 1100111000 0:2.50 1:2.50
> 1110101110 0:1.00 1:2.33
> 1101110000 0:2.50 1:2.50
> 1111000100 0:2.50 1:2.50
> 1110011011 0:1.50 1:2.33
> 1110001000 0:3.00 1:2.00
> 1110001011 0:2.00 1:2.00
> 1110001000 0:3.00 1:2.00
> 1101101010 0:1.00 1:1.50
> 1100111010 0:1.33 1:2.00
> 1100011010 0:1.67 1:1.67
> 1111000011 0:4.00 1:3.00
> 1001111110 0:1.50 1:3.50
> 1100010011 0:2.50 1:1.67
> 1100000010 0:3.50 1:1.50
> 1111010010 0:1.33 1:2.00
> 1101000111 0:2.00 1:2.00
> 1001001011 0:1.67 1:1.25
> 1111000110 0:2.00 1:3.00
> 1000010001 0:3.50 1:1.00
> 1000110111 0:2.00 1:2.00
> 1111000001 0:5.00 1:2.50
> 1100100011 0:2.50 1:1.67
> 1011000110 0:1.67 1:1.67
> 1010011011 0:1.33 1:1.50
> 1101010010 0:1.25 1:1.25
> 1110011100 0:2.00 1:3.00
> 1001101000 0:2.00 1:1.33
> 1111111111 1:10.00
> 0 0:1.00
> ```

Answer (score 6):

```
array = [1111111111, '0000000000', 1111100000, '0011001100', 1010101, '0011', 1100, '', 1, 0, 1100111000, 1110101110, 1101110000, 1101010010, 1110011100, 1001101000]

def weather_ratio(period):
    series_sunny = [len(i) for i in period.split('0') if i]
    series_rainy = [len(i) for i in period.split('1') if i]

    ratio_sunny = ratio_rainy = 0
    if series_sunny:
        ratio_sunny = sum(series_sunny)/len(series_sunny) 
    if series_rainy:
        ratio_rainy = sum(series_rainy)/len(series_rainy)

    return round(ratio_sunny, 1), round(ratio_rainy, 1)


for a in array:
   r, s = weather_ratio(str(a))
   print(f'{a:<10} -> rainy: {r:4}, sunny: {s}')
```

выведет:

```
1111111111 -> rainy: 10.0, sunny: 0
0000000000 -> rainy:    0, sunny: 10.0
1111100000 -> rainy:  5.0, sunny: 5.0
0011001100 -> rainy:  2.0, sunny: 2.0
1010101    -> rainy:  1.0, sunny: 1.0
0011       -> rainy:  2.0, sunny: 2.0
1100       -> rainy:  2.0, sunny: 2.0
           -> rainy:    0, sunny: 0
1          -> rainy:  1.0, sunny: 0
0          -> rainy:    0, sunny: 1.0
1100111000 -> rainy:  2.5, sunny: 2.5
1110101110 -> rainy:  2.3, sunny: 1.0
1101110000 -> rainy:  2.5, sunny: 2.5
1101010010 -> rainy:  1.2, sunny: 1.2
1110011100 -> rainy:  3.0, sunny: 2.0
1001101000 -> rainy:  1.3, sunny: 2.0
```

---

Если разделить строчное представление числа по какому-то разделителю (period = '1100111000' по '0', например), то .split() вернет последовательности противоположных значений: `['11', '', '111', '', '', '']`. Выбрав непустые и разделив их длину количество на количество, получим среднюю длительность непрерывных периодов...

Comment: Нето .1100111000. Надо чтобы считало по сколько периоды с 1 или 0 длятся. Если представить что 1 - дождь ,а 0 - ясно. То  можно 1100111000  представить как, 2 дня дождь, 2 дня ясно ,3 дня дождь, 3 дня ясно .То в среднем дождь идет 2.5 дня также как и 'ясно'

Comment: Мне надо найти по сколько дней дождь в среднем идет так как в варианте 1100111000 - он идет в среднем по 2.5 дня ,а если 1010101010 - идти он будет в среднем по 1 дню

Comment: @ВоваХолод так?